# to concat csv files having different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have 10 csv files with different dimension so I want to concat it there are 10 csv files.
which looks like, so I want to concatenate it make one file but whenever I am doing it the format changes.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I want one csv file[image]

```
dfs = glob.glob(path + '*.csv')

result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df,header=None) for df in dfs])

result.to_csv(path + 'merge.csv',header=None)
```

Comment: You should probably be using `pd.concat([...], axis=1)`, but what is the result of your code? does it throw an error? does it output an unwanted result?

Comment: have you bothered to look at what pd.concat even does? bet you'll find the answer real quick ^

Answer (score 0):

You may want to combine csv files horizontally. Use `axis=1`  , for example,

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('f1.txt')
df2 = pd.read_csv('f2.txt')

combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
combined.to_csv('merged_csv.csv')
```

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(path)

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=[0])
        for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]

result_csv = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
result_csv.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.concat`.

The code below only works for **few** Csv file (3 here)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"address\1.csv",
                  index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"address\2.csv",
                  index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
df3 = pd.read_csv(r"address\3.csv",
                  index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])

finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()
finaldf.to_csv('result.csv')
```

With code below you can concat **infinite** csv file that you want in the same directory :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(path)

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
        for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]

result_csv = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()
result_csv.to_csv('result.csv')
```

and it will save into `result.csv` in that same `path` that you used above.

Comment: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1261, 9), indices imply (467, 9)` gives me this error

Comment: @KrupaliMistry it's just worked for me before I posted it , you can use `join` instead of `concat` I think that will help you with the error

Comment: try this: `dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=[0]) for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('csv')]`

Comment: @KrupaliMistry  `result_csv = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1);`
`result_csv.to_csv('result.csv')`

Comment: @KrupaliMistry I edited the answer check the first section (for few csv)